# Conversion: Can we allow user to provide input for a function in percentages in R?

Tags: r, function

### Question:

I'm wondering how I can define a way such that if a user of a function provided an input value in "percentages" then before using these input values, the function converts these percentages to a corresponding ordinary numeric values to be used in the function?

**Note:** By percentage as input value, I **literally** mean a user could put **12.5%** or **1.5%** etc. and so these values be converted to .125 and .015.

**A simple annotated R example is below:**

```
Accept.percent = function(x) {  # "x" can be as small as ".013" & as large as ".85"
                                # but user can provide "1.3%" to "85%"
cdf <- pbeta(x, 4, 2)           # and we can convert the input values
                                # provided as percentages to a corresponding
  return(cdf)                   # ordinary numeric values before use.

}

## Example of use:

Accept.percent(.013)
```

Comment: @G5W, Do you mean for example `13%/100` is permissible in R! Or I think there is a confusion here, I'm asking that a user can "literally", put `13%` as input value, and then before use, function throw the "%" sign away and divide by 100 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can cut off the % sign, convert to a numeric variable and divide by 100

```
x2 <- as.numeric(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1)) / 100
```

Then use `x2` in your call to `pbeta()`

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a string literal based on the comments in the OP's code. I wonder what the user interface is

Comment: Dear rsoren, thank you (upvoted and accepted), as John said, I was more interested in letting the user directly input `13%` with no quotation marks, is that really possible?

Comment: Is the user typing R code, or inputting it through some other interface?

Comment: Yeah, 13% by itself (without quotes) will give an error because it is incorrect R syntax. If you're using Shiny, you can give the user a ```textInput()``` to type in 13% and it will read it as a character vector. Then you can use the line from my answer

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to allow for the percentage sign too? If not, you can do it by adding a condition and a coorespondong argument:

```
my_fun <- function(x, percentage = FALSE){
  if (percentage) x <- x/100

  (rest of function goes here) 
}
```